# How can I fast identify complexity of code below and in any other code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int (*d)[2], int n)
{
      int p = 0, cnt;
      for (int i=2; i*i <= n; ++i)
      {
             for (cnt = 0; n % i == 0; cnt++, n /= i) {}
             if (cnt == 0)
                  continue;
             d[p][0] =  i;
             d[p++][1] = cnt;
      }
      if (n > 1)
      {
             d[p][0] = n;
             d[p++](l] = 1;
      }
      return p;
}
```

So as far as I understand when I m looking for complexity, I m looking for loops. The first loop is trivial. It gives us `O(sqrt(n))`, but there is a second loop which decreases n, I don t really understand this moment. Experiments show that complexity is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: It depends on n for prime n its sqrt(n) for highley composite numbers its log(n) for others it depends. So it's O(sqrt(n)) but not Theta(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Why do you need to know? This particular example looks like something where I would be completely satisfied with a value from just testing it, without theoretical calculations.

Comment: And to the question "how can i fast identify complexity in any code" the answer is, you cannot. There is no magic bullet. The more skilled you are, the faster you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking of the second loop : n % i == 0; and n=n/i; if we loop in the for loop we will have in the first iteration n=n/i/i .... in the k iteration we are going to have n/(i^k) and this will stop when n%i!=0; lets say n/(i^k)==1 so 1%i==1 !=0  so from n/(i^k)==1 we are going to have k=log(n) in i base which mean log(n)

Comment: But what if n is prime then n%i == 0 is never true.

Comment: Yes i know i just tried to show him an example of how  can this loop be translated into an O(log n )